# How to upload files from browser without using base64 encoding?

Tags: html, angular, groovy, file-upload, filereader

I have existing upload code that lets the user select a file using the regular HTML input file selection dialog then uses HTML FileReader.readAsDataURL to get the file as a Base64 string and POST to the server where it is Base64 decoded and saved.

I have now been asked to handle very large files (a few hundred MB I think), and therefore to switch from using Base64 encoding as it will hammer the browser and the server.
How do I do this with the least work possible, and/or what are my options here?
Looks like FileReader has readAsArrayBuffer or readAsBinaryString (not on IE, but that's OK), but not sure how to adapt my code to use these.

I think this question is language/framework agnostic (as basically about what HTML/JS functions to use) but for what it's worth my front end is Angular and my backend Groovy/Grails (i.e. Java).

Client:

```
uploadMyFile(name: string):void {

let fr: FileReader = new FileReader();

// Set up the event handler for the FileReader, triggered once the user selected file has been loaded locally (e.g. from a local drive)
fr.onload = (e) => {
  uploadArgs.fileContent = fr.result;

  this.handleUploads.uploadTheFile(name, fr.result) // See code block below for uploadTheFile
    .subscribe((response) => {
         // Confirm upload
      },
      (reason) => {
         // handle error
      });
};
// Read the data in locally (e.g. from a local drive), this triggers the fr.onload() event defined above. (Read as Base64)
fr.readAsDataURL(this.fileToUpload);
}
```

also client:

```
uploadTheFile(name:string, content:any):Observable<MyUploadResult> {
const formData: FormData = new FormData();
formData.append('fileName', name);
formData.append('fileContent', content);
return this.http.post<MyUploadResult>("uploadURL", formData, this.httpUploadJSONOptions).pipe(
  tap(),
  catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) => this.handleError(err)));
```

}

Server - does some validation, then decodes the content that was received as a base64 string, into a byte array, relevant bit of code:

```
// Remove Data-URL declaration "data:*/*;base64," from start of upload leaving just Base64-encoded file data:
String base64Str = cmd.fileContent.substring(cmd.fileContent.indexOf(",") + 1)
BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder()
byte[] decodedContent = decoder.decodeBuffer(base64Str)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48163792/uploading-a-large-file-1gb-to-grails3

Comment: I never use Base64Encoding string to upload a file because it is weird (I knew some developers is still using this way for small file under 20Mb but I prefer you to read carefully about Multipart in your case, about your Memory and CPU cost both client and server side). If you detect this is a huge problem on your client side, you should prevent it by changing from Base64 to Multipart. Multipart isn't only preventing more troubles in Encode/Decode phase but also it is natural in HTTP protocol. I don't think Grails doesn't support Multipart.

Comment: Thanks guys. OK looks like it should be multipart, but what changes should I make on the client side to my code above?